# Access the underlying value of resource.data for list query in firestore security rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Within firestore security rules, is there a way to get direct access to the value of a `resource.data` for a list query? More specifically, for `array-contains`. I’d like to use the value of the `list` query and do some transformations with it inside the rules before evaluating the result.

Example:

Let’s assume that `admin1` is the currently loggedin user.

I have a list of resources with the following property:

```
someResource{
    sharedWithIds: ["client1", "client2", ..., "admin1", "admin2", ..., "admin1_client1", ...] //basically a manual index
}
```

And a query:

```
getDocs(query(collection, where("sharedWithIds", "array-contains", "admin1_client1"))
```

Security rules must only grant access if the current user is listed in `sharedWithIds`

So I was hoping I could do the following in the rules:

```
match /resources/{resourceId}{
    allow list: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.sharedWithIds.split(“_”)
}
```

Here I assume that `resource.data.sharedWithIds` equals to `"admin1_client1"`, which is the value of the query. But it didn’t work - it just gives me `false` all the time.

In fact, the rule's `debug` gives the following output for `resource.data.sharedWithIds`:

```
constraint_value {
  simple_constraints {
    comparator: LIST_CONTAINS
    value {
      string_value: "admin1_client1"
    }
  }
}
```

I wasn't able to find any documentation on this structure, but apparently I can perform `hasAny`, but I can’t figure out how to get the underlying value of `"admin1_client1"`.

Any suggestions? Or is it a dead end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through different questions and related comments on SO, it seems like it's not possible to get the value of the `array-contains` query in the rules. At least not now.

In the rules for some queries we receive the query's value directly, like for `==`. For other queries we only get some internal wrapper object that only exposes a specific method.

That method only allows to test against the specific action related to the query - in case of `array-contains` we only have `hasAny()`

While that allows to do the specific job defined in the doc, it seems like it enforces unnecessary limitations on what can be done in the rules. As opposite if we could get the value of the query itself, this would allow for more flexible rules.

For example in case of `array-contains`, rules could expose the value that user provided in the query or an array like `[value]` - this would allow to test the query in the same way it works right now, plus it would allow for additional manipulations.

The current approach of how the rules work unfortunately limits more complex scenarios.

*As a remark, while Frank's answer mentions that there is no way to manipulate the data, that wasn't really my question, so I'm posting my answer to complete it*

Answer (score 3):

There is no way in Firestore security rules to manipulate the data.

The best solution I can think of is to include the separate parts you want to check on the in `sharedWithIds` too, or add another array field with the split values for this purpose.

Comment: ok thanks Frank, got that. For the separate parts, can you give an example of such a request? I was thinking about separate arrays too, but that would require two `array-contains` within a conjunction, which is not allowed, unless I misunderstand it. Apparently what could solve it is `where("sharedWithIds", "array-contains-all", ['client1', 'admin1'])`, but there is no `array-contains-all` - I can see a ticket for that, but there is no visible activity there. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/220676303?pli=1

Comment: I guess "manipulate" in my question was a bit misleading - I really just want to read the value from `resource.data.sharedWithIds`, not that I want to change it in the query itself within the rules. Still no chance? Maybe a function like get()/getValue() or something? I've updated that part of the question.

Comment: There's simply no way to perform an operation on each element in the array field, as that would require the rules engine to test each document - and that wouldn't scale. --- But if I understand the requirements correctly, you can have the client perform its current query on the `admin1_client1` and then have the rule check for the `auth.uid` in the same array or in another field. You'll need to duplicate some values to allow that, but that's pretty common when working with NoSQL databases.

Comment: Yes, your understanding of the requirements seem to be correct - and using the same array to test against `auth.uid` is exactly what I'm trying to do. But how? Maybe the following example will show my problem better: if I perform a `list` request with `==`, i.e. `where("sharedWithIds", "==", "admin1_client1”)`, then in the rules I get what I expect, I.e `resource.data.sharedWithIds.split("_")` gives `[“ admin1”, “client1”]` and I can test this against `auth.uid`. But for `array-contains` this doesn’t work as per my question, even though the underlying value is still `”admin1_client1”`

Comment: *There's simply no way to perform an operation on each element in the array field, as that would require the rules engine to test each document - and that wouldn't scale.* - yes, that’s clear. However `resource.data` in the context of `list` request refers to the `query` value itself and it doesn’t require access to the database/documents so there shouldn’t be any issues with that, unless I misunderstand you. And the `query value` is just enough in my case, it's just I can't get access to it for `array-contains`

Comment: The problem is that you do `split` on the array elements, and the rules engine can't determine what to do with that. The only thing it *can* do is to ensure the array field contains a certain completely element (or not).

Comment: Yeah, as `debug` suggested it's some kind of `constraint  object`, not even an array. I though tried to treat it as array/list and even brute forced a few more methods, but no success. Like `resource.data.sharedWithIds[0]`, `sharedWithIds.get()` etc. The only thing it seem to support is `hasAny([...])`. Do you know if this `constraint  object` has any other methods available at all? Or is it really not possible to read that value? If it was possible, that could enable more flexible rules.

Comment: ok, I guess it's not possible to get the value of the `array-contains` query. I'm gonna post my own answer with what I was able to find so far. If you have any additional information on how those internal wrappers work, that would be very helpful.